# Why CString MakeUpper inconsistent performance in DEBUG and Release?

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am facing a strange problem in VC++6.0.

```
CString m_strData = "W" + CString(char(165));
m_strData.MakeUpper();
MessageBox(m_strData, "Alert from C++",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
```

If I build the project with Win32 Debug, the alert value is correct. But if I build with Win32 Release MinDependency. The value is different with Win32 Debug. Why?  Is their any article show me the reason? I have tried setlocale(LC_ALL,"English_United States.1250") front of the code, but it didn't work.

the value of Win32 Debug
    [image: Win32 Debug]

the value of Win32 Release MinDepency

[image: Win32 Release MinDepency]

I've take a look into the CString MakeUpper function. It will call _tcsupr() function. But from the MSDN page, it only shows me this function will depends on the locale. But not the project Build mode...?

Comment: What do you mean "the value is different?"  Example?

Comment: from the display value in MessageBox

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: It is simple, the codes I've provide in the question.

Comment: Please show the *message*, both of them. Preferably as text and not screenshots.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg   when build with Win32 Debug, it prompt me W? in the messagebox,  but in Win32 Release MinDepency, it prompt me just blank(although there some invisible characters)

Answer (score 1):

The output of char(165) depends on the codepage you are using. It could be the Yen-symbol or an N with a ~ above it. I assume that the code generated in debugging either uses different codepage or replaces the character with a question mark to tell you, that it is a non-printable character.

Comment: Did you mean Debug and Release will use different codepage?  Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: That is only an assumption. You could probably give me a -1 for not prooving it first, but I think the info could still be useful.

Comment: What you could do to narrow down on the problem is to create a loop that goes through your string and display messageboxes for each character's ascii value. That way you could verify that the contents of the string is the same for debug and relase mode. Once you verified that you know that your code does the same in both modes. If that is the case (which I think it is) it can only be the additonal debug code, that visual studio generate behind the scenes. In that case I would stick to my answer, that the '?' is service to help you see that there could be a problem in release mode.